# js: chrome says "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" or "Failed to load resource" on html5 video elements

Tags: javascript, html, debian, html5-video

I have a classic HTML/Javascript/CSS setup, which plays videos in html5 `<video>` elements.

The site works fine in Firefox and Edge, but Chrome throws either `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED 206`or `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error messages.

The connection is `https`the server is a Apache/2.4.25 (Debian). Happens on `.mp4` and `.ogg` files.

You can see the site on https://video.fogodosamba.de/. You can see the sourcecode there too, obviously. Has anyone an educated guess on whats happening.

It happens ONLY in chrome.